# Reduce multiple nested includes for the same table into a single query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to reduce my SQL queries in a controller action and have the following query

```
@event = Event.includes(
  :outgoing_orders => [:organisation],
  :outgoing_invoices => [:organisation]
).find(params[:id])
```

This works well, but I wanted to know if there was a way that the nested `organisation` includes could be grouped so that they produce a single Organisation Load query rather than being called multiple times.

So something like this

```
Event Load
OutgoingOrder Load
Organisation Load
OutgoingInvoice Load
Organisation Load
```

would be reduced to this

```
Event Load
OutgoingOrder Load
OutgoingInvoice Load
Organisation Load
```